# Moderator election: |candidates| = |positions available|

Tags: discussion, election

Firstly I welcome all the candidates, and I hope their nomination will be successful. :-)

Here I see a little... uncommon thingy. We have two positions, and also two candidates.

Is it for sure okay? On this way, maybe the candidates could become simply appointed candidates, too.

Comment: This has been addressed on the main meta: ["if the number of candidates == slots, the election ends early and the candidates will get appointed."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315071/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. So, why didn't it happen yet like that?

Comment: @Mast: From Andrew's link: "We don't have any automation for this right now and [yesterday]'s a holiday in the US"

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment about closing out election related questions.  I think Meta will be fine as is.